# Biblatex: ifx inside DeclareFieldFormat

Tags: biblatex, conditionals

I'm not having any luck using an `\ifx` command inside a `\DeclareFieldFormat` block with biblatex (v1.6). Is there something I'm missing? A minimal (non-)working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{ref1,
    title = {Title1},
    eprint = {MR001},
    eprinttype = {mrnumber}}
@misc{ref2,
    title = {Title},
    eprint = {002},
    eprinttype = {mrnumber}}
@misc{ref3,
    title = {Title},
    eprint = {MR003 (aa)},
    eprinttype = {mrnumber}}
@misc{ref4,
    title = {Title},
    eprint = {004 (bb)},
    eprinttype = {mrnumber}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% based on code from http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1856/245
\def\checkMR MR#1#2#3 #4\relax%
  {\ifx#1M%
     \ifx#2R%
     #3%
     \else%
     #1#2#3%
     \fi
   \else
     #1#2#3%
   \fi}
\def\MR#1{\checkMR MR#1 \relax}

\DeclareFieldFormat{eprint:mrnumber}{%
  \MR{#1}}

\begin{document}
It works here \MR{MR001}, \MR{002}, \MR{MR003 (aa)}, \MR{004 (bb)}

\cite{ref1}, \cite{ref2}, \cite{ref3}, \cite{ref4}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

It evaluates correctly in the body, but as false in the bibliography field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because you are using the `\ifx` test, which will only be true if the category codes of `M` and `R` are 'letter'. `biblatex` is passing the argument as a detokenized string, so the test fails. What you want here is to compare by character code: use the `\if` test.

```
\def\checkMR MR#1#2#3 #4\relax
  {%
    \if#1M%
      \if#2R%
        #3%
      \else
        #1#2#3%
      \fi
    \else
      #1#2#3%
    \fi
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

It's possible also to avoid a conditional:

```
\def\checkMR MR#1#2#3 #4\relax%
  {\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1#2}{MR}=0
     #3%
   \else
     #1#2#3%
   \fi}
```

If one wants compatibility with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX, then

```
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
\makeatletter
\def\checkMR MR#1#2#3 #4\relax%
  {\ifnum\pdf@strcmp{#1#2}{MR}=\z@
     #3%
   \else
     #1#2#3%
   \fi}
\makeatother
```

`\pdfstrcmp{<A>}{<B>}` expands to 0 if the two strings `<A>` and `<B>` are equal (after expansion). Unfortunately it's called `\strcmp` in XeTeX and is missing in LuaTeX, but H. Oberdiek's **pdftexcmds** package comes to the rescue.

Comment: Of course, this needs pdfTeX >= 1.30, or XeTeX >= 0.9994.